# how to make when opening the discord bot it write in a specific channel that it's working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready(ctx):
   if ctx.channel.id == status_channel_id:
      await ctx.send("[WOL] : Working")
```

I'm using python I want it when I open the discord bot it says "[WOL] : Working" in a specific channel.

```
This is my error :
1, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

Comment: The error seems crystal clear.  The `on_ready` event does not get a context parameter.  It's not part of a channel at that point.

Comment: then how to make it so when I start the bot it sends a message to the specific channel?

Comment: You say "the specific channel", but there IS no channel yet.  You can use `bot.get_channel(...)` to fetch the channel by its identifier, then `channel.send` will work.

Comment: I used developer mode to find the channel id and assign it to a variable